# Printing out element in the ith postion in a list in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
f=open('julyTemps.txt')
for li in f.readlines():
   data = li.strip().split(' ')
   print data[1]
```

This code give me an out of range error and the list is of length 3.
please help

Comment: print what data is and you probably can figure out the reason.

Comment: Please include a one-line version of `julyTemps.txt` that causes it to fail.

Comment: Using your code and my own textfile, it works. So please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: @RichieHindle one line version is **1 91 70**

Comment: @peterodhiambo: For me, your code works perfectly with that input.

Comment: @RichieHindle so how would format your code to print out **1 91 70**?

Comment: @peterodhiambo: Your questions make no sense.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and then open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('julyTemps.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.strip().split(' ')
        if len(data) > 1
            print data[1]
        else:
            print 'this line does not split as it should:\n%s' % line
```

Comment: props for the `with` statement but you should also get rid of `.readlines()` to make the code perfect (readlines stores all lines in memory at once)